# Changing array values within a recursive function using a for...of loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, recursion

In the following recursive function, I'm very confused about the order in which each console log occurs. Can someone explain why this is happening?

The code,

```js
const names = [{ name: 'tim' }, { name: 'bob' }, { name: 'john' }]

const nameStuff = ({ names, targetName, array = [], count = 0 }) => {
  console.log('count', count)

  let matchFound = false
  array[count] = names[count]

  console.log('array[count]', array[count])

  if (array[array.length - 1] === targetName) {
    matchFound = true
    return array
  }

  if (names.length > 0) {
    count++
    for (const nameObj of names) {
      if (nameObj.name === targetName) {
        array[count] = names[count]
        return array
      }
      nameStuff({ names: name, targetName, array, count })
    }
  }

  return matchFound ? array : undefined
}

const result = nameStuff({ names, targetName: 'bob' })

console.log('result', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Results in,

```
'count' 0
'count' 1
'array[count]' { name: 'tim' }
'array[count]' undefined
'result' [ { name: 'tim' }, { name: 'bob' } ]
```

Why do both `count`s log before the first `array[count]`? I would expect it to look like this,

```
'count' 0
'array[count]' { name: 'tim' }
'count' 1
'array[count]' undefined
'result' [ { name: 'tim' }, { name: 'bob' } ]
```

Furthermore, why is the second log of `array[count]` not `{name: 'bob'}`?

Comment: If you use SO snippet, you'll see that it logs something very different from your results.

Comment: As @GerardoFurtado said, what you've said is the output isn't the output of the code in the question. (I've copied your code into a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).) We can't answer the question "why do both `count`s log before the first `array[count]`?" because the code in the question doesn't do that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry about that. I'm using a MacOS JavaScript playground app that is outputting what I posted.  But as I used JSFiddle, I see now that the app must either have an issue, or I have it set up incorrectly.  Thank you.